# How to calculate MSE for a Mini-batch?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, conv-neural-network, loss-function

It is known that MSE can be expressed as follows

[image: MSE]

where k is the number of output nodes (classes). This expression can calculate the error for one training example.

Suppose that I want to calculate MSE for a mini-batch of N examples, is it correct to add another summation to sum this error for all the N examples in the mini-batch as follows? in other words, Is it correct to use the below equation to calculate the MSE for a mini-batch?

[image]

Comment: I'm having the exact same question. The tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(...) sugests that you can take the average of the different MSE's. Take a look at the SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE in tf.keras.losses.Reduction. Also take a look a multi-output regression on wiki. I'll come back here if I do find an awnser. I guess the answer relies on what exactly you are trying to do, and what makes sence in your circumstances